# How do i fix doubling of close, minimize buttons, problem with unite extension

Tags: gnome-shell-extension

After an update for some reason the close, minimize etc. buttons are doubling instead of moving in firefox. This also happens in the software center.

Is this fixable?

[image: doubling]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging through the extensions website I found the solution.

In Firefox, under customize, you can check off 'title bar' in the bottom left - restart firefox, and it should be fixed again.

Reference here: https://github.com/hardpixel/unite-shell/issues/201#issuecomment-697957246